# Transfering web site from C to D drive on dedicated server

Tags: android, http, web, server, dedicated

How can I transfer web site (adjunted with andorid application) from C drive to D drive on a dedicated server which has windows operating system because when I simply move it the application's (the web site works fine) links do not work and I get server error when using the application?

Should I make changes to httpaccess or something similar, per se where is the place where I need to make the changes in the http protocol concering link forwarding from default location in C drive to D (and vice versa)?

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to set the "DocumentRoot" setting inside your webserver application to the correct new value, where the folder with the website itself resides in.
Also, keep your links inside the website "clean", which means, they should all be relative to the document-root ("/").